# How to configure jetty to put logs into an external file

Tags: logging, jetty

How to configure jetty to put its logs into an external file?

[Manual says](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html#configuring-jetty-logging) that I have to put slf4j into the lib directory.

What I did was:

- download slf4j and put slf4j-log4j12-1.7.3.jar into $JETTY_HOME$/lib .
- download log4j and put log4j-1.2.17.jar into $JETTY_HOME$/lib
- create a log4j configuration file. it's available from below:

---

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />    
  <param name="File" value="c:/app/jetty/logs/server.log" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <priority value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
```

- commented line

  `"#org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog"` in `$JETTY_HOME$/resources/jetty-logging.properties`

Although I did everything what's described above, I am not able to see any logs in the target destinations. All log entries are still available from the console

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Updated Instructions (June 2016)

For Jetty 9+, you'll be using a split `${jetty.home}` and `${jetty.base}` directory.

> Note: do not edit/modify/delete/add/remove any content in `${jetty.home}`.  All of your configuration will reside in `${jetty.base}` from now on.

Instructions as command line:

```sh
$ mkdir /path/to/mybase
$ cd /path/to/mybase

# Prepare a basic jetty.base directory
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,resources,ext
INFO: ext             initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: resources       initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: server          initialised (transitively) in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: http            initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
INFO: deploy          initialised in ${jetty.base}/start.ini
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/lib/ext
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/resources
MKDIR: ${jetty.base}/webapps
INFO: Base directory was modified

# Download the required jar files
$ cd /path/to/mybase/lib/ext
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar

# Prepare the Jetty side logging to use slf4j
$ cd /path/to/mybase/resources
$ echo "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog" > jetty-logging.properties

# Grab a copy of a log4j.xml to initialize things
$ cd /path/to/mybase/resources
$ curl -o log4j.xml https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joakime/13e31db59b83079be3fdc1a877de7060/raw/5c275a2a2f29445d6cdde7fcae3820da99e7234b/log4j.xml

# Start Jetty
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

> Note: do not enable the `logging` module as that is strictly for Jetty's `StdErrLog` implementation.  That `logging` module will capture any `System.err` and `System.out` and redirect it to a rolling log file.  This capture and redirect will be in direct conflict with your log4j `ConsoleAppender`!

## Original Instructions - Only valid on Jetty 8 (now EOL) and older

Follow these steps:

1. create a logging directory in `$JETTY_HOME/lib`: `$JETTY_HOME/lib/logging` (this is just best practice)
2. put `log4j`, `slf4j-log4j` and `slf4j-api` in that directory: 
   e.g.: `log4j-1.2.16.jar`  `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar`  `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar`
3. make sure to have that new directory in jetty's classpath by adding "`logging`" in your `$JETTY_HOME/start.ini` `OPTIONS` line: 
   e.g.: `OPTIONS=Server,websocket,resources,ext,jsp,jdbc,logging`
4. place your `log4j.properties` in `$JETTY_HOME/resources` directory
5. start jetty

If your log4j.properties is properly setup this should work for you. I'll take care to have such a step by step guide in the documentation.

Comment: If you are using Jetty 9, you have 1 more step.  exit the $JETTY_HOME/resources/jetty-logging.properties to have this 1 line ... `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog`

Comment: Documentation for this has been updated ... [Example: Logging with Apache Log4j](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-log4j.html)

Comment: I am using Jetty9,followed your steps,but get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory** exception.