# How to direct embedded Jetty server logs to a file?

Tags: logging, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

When I start Jetty server in my application (i.e. Jetty is embedded here), all the logs, by default are redirected to StdErr. I want the logs to be redirected to a file instead. How can I do that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

PLease try add this section to your jetty.xml(You may need to modify according to your need).

```
<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
          <Arg><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
          <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
          <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
          <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
          <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </New>

    <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref id="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
```

And also please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474476/how-to-configure-jetty-to-put-logs-into-an-external-file). It seems on be on the same line of yours.

[Update]:

For embedded jetty, you need to explicitly add jetty.xml and configure it programatically. Example code:

```
private static final String JETTY_CONFIG_LOCATION= "/etc/secured_jetty.xml";  
<<Skipped>>
URL jettyConfig = bundle.getResource(JETTY_CONFIG_LOCATION); 
XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(jettyConfig); 
Server root = (Server) xmlConfig.configure()
```

Comment: Well, but I am using an embedded jetty. It doesn't really have a jetty XML. Jetty is launched and set using Java code in my application and it doesn't have a jetty.xml. Do I need to create one and point to it or can I just write code to send the logs to a file ?

Comment: You need to add a jetty.xml in you application and configure it with the code. Typically this is done using XMLConfigurtaion class. Please see the below code:                                                                                      URL jettyConfig = bundle.getResource(JETTY_CONFIG_LOCATION);
XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(jettyConfig);
Server root = (Server)  xmlConfig.configure();